# I need a material that isn't reflected by other objects roughness (img example)

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor, shaders

The letters have a white material
The platform below has a material with low roughness that act like a mirror
I want a material for letters that can't be reflected on the platform.
[image]

Comment: hello, are you in Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: I use Eevee <3 Merry Christmas

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "light path" node and connect the "is reflection ray" on the numbers material and plug it into a mix shader combined with a transparency shader. This way the numbers wont show up in reflections.

Comment: It doesn't work in Eevee ,Thank you for the answer.Merry Christmas!